# Decimals and Strings

Tags: .net, vb6

I have a database table with a decimal(25) datatype.  The data from this column is loaded into a variable in VB.NET.  There are no calculations done on the variable in .NET.  Shall I use a decimal data type or a String datatype in .NET?

The same database field is used in a VB6 application.  No calculations are done on the field in VB6.  What is the best datatype to use in VB6?

The only time the variable is used in either program is as follows:

```
If variable <> 0 Then
    'Do some logic
End If
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally, being strongly typed is better, but from your question it wouldn't seem to matter. Personally, I would make it a decimal because what if a calculation were needed to be done on it in the future? You never know what the next developer will be doing to your code so always try to make it as robust as you can.

Comment: I agree but also dissagree.  Personally I would use the decimal if you were to select the data but why not just select a bool right from the database?  Also you should not strive to make your code robust as it can be... but rather as lean as it could be... avoid gold plating etc.. .etc... do the simplest thing that could work... oh but I upvote this because I agree...

Comment: It is an ID field in the database, so a calculation will never have to be done.  I think a String is better because there is less overhead.  There are a lot of iterations.  What do you think?

Comment: jsobo nailed it. If you're going to use it to only ever do a conditional check, then why not set a bool.

Comment: Surely it is wasting resources using a decimal.  There are a lot of iterations and it slows it down?

Comment: Unless you're working on a performance critical system (such as a mobile phone) I wouldn't worry about the overhead of the decimal vs string. It's minimal really.

Answer (score 2):

Simply put, if it's a decimal number, use a decimal data type, if it's string data, use a string data type, if it's a flag, use a boolean, etc.

Also note that using decimal value as an ID is a bad Idea as computers can't always represent them accurately (Google for floating point inaccuracy).

Answer (score 0):

Definitely use the `Decimal` datatype in .NET.

VB6 has a Decimal datatype but you can't use it directly.  However, you can do it like this:

```
Dim MyDecimal As Variant
MyDecimal = CDec(rs(rowIndex).Value)
```

That is, the `CDec` function will convert to the internal decimal type, which you can store in a `Variant` variable.  Unfortunately you lose strong typing, but I think it's better than using a floating point representation.